# In reStructuredText greek alpha needs "\\", other greek letters only "\" when target is pdf

Tags: latex, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I recently discovered reST/Sphinx and tried to use it to document a python class I had written some time before.

After some experimentation I found out I needed to write `` :math:`K_\\alpha` `` to get the greek letter in the subscript while using the `make latexpdf` target. With a single `\` there were errors. Strangely enough every other greek letter only needed a single `\` to produce the desired output.

What is happening?

Answer (score 6):

Thank you so much for asking this.  It finally helped me solve my related problem.

For me, \alpha and \beta both fail.
They both fail even without the subscript part coming into play.  But if I use the curly braces it works:

```
:math:`\alpha`
```

does not compile

```
:math:`{\alpha}`
```

gives me the symbol I want

```
:math:`{\\alpha}`
```

gives me the word 'alpha' written as adjacent math variables a, l, p, h, a.

Answer (score 3):

To get a `K` followed by a subscripted `α` in inline text, use

```
:math:`K_{\alpha}`
```

Note curly braces and backticks. It works fine and is what you would expect based on these references:

- http://www.emerson.emory.edu/services/latex/latex_117.html
- http://sphinx-doc.org/ext/math.html#role-math

In math markup used in Python docstrings, you need two backslashes (or use "raw" strings):

```
:math:`K_{\\alpha}`
```

---

Edit: I was wrong about the curly braces. It turns out that these two samples give the same result in the PDF output:

```
:math:`K_{\alpha}`
```

and

```
:math:`K_\alpha`
```

Comment: Well, as I wrote, the single \ version works ok, just not with `\alpha`. E.g. `\beta` ist fine. It is irrelevant if there are `{}` around it or not.

Comment: I don't know what else to say. Both `\alpha` and `\beta` work fine for me using the syntax in my answer. I use Sphinx 1.1.3 and MikTex 2.9.

Comment: Ok. I use a linux system and, oddly enough, vim is showing me that `\alpha` will be interpreted as `\a lpha`, because it colors the `a` diffrently from the rest. With double slashes it's ok..

Comment: So this is just a problem with text highlighting in vim?

Comment: Er no. It's just that vim seams to know that alpha needs a second `\\`. It highlights it diffrently than all the other greek names, so there might be a an obscure specification, which vim knows about, but I don't.

Answer (score 3):

> What is happening?

\a is interpreted as a control character ("bell", just like e.g. \n "end of line"). Notably, \b (backspace) could be a control character as well, but is for some reason not interpreted as such.

Note that another possible workaround is using *raw strings* (`r"""some text"""`), as noted also in the sphinx math documentation [2](http://sphinx-doc.org/latest/ext/math.html).

Sources: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character), [Sphinx documentation, "Math support in Sphinx"](http://sphinx-doc.org/latest/ext/math.html)